# Rigid body falls through static mesh even though collision is detected

Tags: collision-detection, 3d, collision-resolution, physics-engine

I'm using [Jitter Physics](https://github.com/mattleibow/jitterphysics) to create a game. For testing, I have ball (a spherical rigid body) falling onto a small box-like mesh. The problem is that the ball falls straight through the floor, even though the collision seems to be detected properly.

[image: Ball (spherical rigid body) falling onto a custom mesh.]

The mesh's rigid body is created using a triangle mesh shape. In the code below, model is the floor's 3D model

```
Octree octree = PhysicsUtilities.ExtractOctree(model);
octree.BuildOctree();

Body body = new RigidBody(new TriangleMeshShape(octree));
body.IsStatic = true;
```

The `PhysicsUtilities.ExtractOctree` function extracts vertices from the 3D model in order to create the rigid body. As far as I can tell, that function is working correctly (i.e. all vertices and indices look correct). To check if the collision was detected, I added a callback function as follows.

```
CollisionSystem collisionSystem = new CollisionSystemSAP();
collisionSystem.CollisionDetected += OnCollisionDetected;

World world = new World(collisionSystem);
```

The ball-floor collision is detected and everything about the collision looks correct. I've even tried changing values in `world.ContactSettings`, but nothing worked.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? I've tried everything I can and Jitter's documentation is pretty low.

Answer (score 1):

Collision detection has very little to do with *collision response*, besides triggering it.

Check your settings for both bodies, and the settings for the physics system:

1. Collision callbacks: Is there a collision behaviour for each body?
2. Body density: if density is too low, objects float through each other.
3. Mass: physics needs this to compute kinematic response and normal forces. make sure the value is set.